# Reparing GNOME desktop

Tags: gnome

I have installed Ubuntu 16 LTE OS on my PC and wanted to install gnome desktop on it. After installation of GNOME desktop whenever I log in it the desktop always open 180 degree inverted. Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu have you installed?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** what is the output of `lsb_release --code`

Comment: What's your 'xrandr -q' output? What is the monitor label?